# Flutter web - enable scrolling with up/down arrow keys with scroll controller

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

I have a simple `ListView` wrapped in a `SingleChildScrollView` as follows. If no controller is specified, I can scroll the the list with up/down arrow keys, page up/down keys as well as space bar on Chrome. However, if I specify a scroll controller by uncommenting the line towards the bottom, scrolling with those keys does not work (I can still scroll by manually dragging the scroll bar up and down).

How do I preserve the scrolling behavior while specifying a scroll controller? I need the scroll controller as I have a listener attached to it to prefetch API data as it gets to the bottom to enable infinite scrolling.

Thanks!

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class SampleScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const SampleScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Widget widget = ListView.builder(
      shrinkWrap: true,
      itemCount: 10,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return Container(
          height: 100,
          color: Colors.red[index * 100],
          child: Center(
            child: Text(
              'List tile $index',
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );

    widget = SingleChildScrollView(
      // controller: ScrollController(),
      child: widget,
    );

    return widget;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its because you have wrapped list view with a SingleChildScrollView.  Both widgets have the option to scroll. The scroll controller is to be assigned to the list view if that's the primary widget. Also you defined both list view and SingleChildScrollView as widget

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class SampleScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const SampleScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Widget widget = ListView.builder(
     controller: ScrollController(),//<--- add controller here
      shrinkWrap: true,
      itemCount: 10,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return Container(
          height: 100,
          color: Colors.red[index * 100],
          child: Center(
            child: Text(
              'List tile $index',
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );

    //widget = SingleChildScrollView(
      // controller: ScrollController(),
  //    child: widget,
  //  );

    return widget;
  }
}
```

Comment: The `ListView` in my example is a sample, cooked up widget. In reality, I have a bunch of widgets, stacked in a column. If I don't wrap it in a `SingleChildScrollView`, I get an overflow screen error.

Comment: If you have a SingleChildScrollView wrapping the list view then add physics : NeverScrollableScrollPhysics () to the list view

Answer (score 0):

You can use this [updown_arrow_scroller](https://pub.dev/packages/updown_arrow_scroller) package.
After adding this dependency you just need to give the same scroll controller to the Widget provided by the package & its child.